# Calculate lower and upper quartile of SQLiteDB via query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, xampp

I want to calculate the upper and the lower quartile of the value what I call "diffs" in these [fiddle with my DB and the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1a82/21)

How can I do this with SQLite?

There's an extension on the http://www.sqlite.org/contrib?orderby=date, extension-functions.c, which has these commands.

If this is a sufficient solutionf for my problem? How can I integrate this in my Windows-XAMPP Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here 2 versions that compute the Upper Quartile (Q3):

- **Option 1:** Compute the Q3 position and get the average of the values in between.
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f19/5
  [image]
  Source: [How to Calculate the Upper Quartile](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Upper-Quartile)
- **Option 2 (More accurate):** Compute the Q3 position and give more weight to the closest position (interpolate). This approach is the same as `QUARTILE.EXC` in MS Excel. 
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f19/6

NOTE: If you want to implement `QUARTILE`/`QUARTILE.INC` that use N-1, you can do so by decrementing the size instead of incrementing it.  `SELECT @Q3_POS = 0.75*(COUNT(*)-1.00) from [Table1]`

[image]

Source: [Why Excel has Multiple Quartile Functions and How to Replicate the Quartiles from R and Other Statistical Packages](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/why-excel-has-multiple-quartile-functions-and-how-to-replicate-the-quartiles-from-r-and-other-statistical-packages/)

More testing:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca246/1  Position close to the upper value (Q3 position: 6.75)
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef046b/1 Position in the middle (7.5)
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2a49/1  Position close to the lower value (8.25)
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f48c/1  Exact Position (9)

Answer (score 2):

I found a [rather unpleasant approach](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1a82/45) based on [this blog post](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/calculating-nth-percentile-in-mysql.html) - basically, use GROUP_CONCAT to list all the values in order, and substring functions to extract the one at the 25th or 75th percentile.

Answer (score -1):

I have calculated both Upper and Lower quartiles in your Query itself.

Please Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f1a82/31/0

Basically the logic is:

- Upper quartile == Average( "highest number"  AND Average( "whole data" ) )
- Lower quartile == Average( "lowest number"  AND Average( "whole data" ) )

Hence the query logic added was:

```
((MIN(diff)+ AVG(diff)) / 2) AS lowerQuartile,
((MAX(diff)+ AVG(diff)) / 2) AS upperQuartile,
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Meier please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the First Quartile should be 21, the Median should be 30 and the third quartile should be 70. I haven't seen this way of calculating the first and the third quartile before...are you sure it is correct?

Comment: No, that won't calculate the quartiles correctly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile, in general the quartiles are not related to the mean.